Apache Sedona pyspark version issues
After trying out code with jupyter notebook from with the apache/sedona:latest Docker container. I wanted to try and execute as python script.
From the container I read the library versions I could hopefully use with the container. I installed:

pyspark==3.4.1
apache-sedona[spark]==1.6.1
with pip.

I forwared the ports:

4040,
4041
8080
8081
8888

Further versions are:

python 3.12 on my windows machine, 3.10 on the container
the container uses: Spark Version: 3.4.1 and has no Scala installed, but JDK 19.

I start the script with:
from sedona.spark import *
from sedona.sql import ST_GeoHash, ST_MakeValid

start_time = time.time()

from sedona.spark import *

config = (
    SedonaContext.builder()
    .config(
        "spark.jars.packages",
        "org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.0_2.12:1.6.1," "org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.6.1-28.2",
    )
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/repository/unidata-all")
    .getOrCreate()
)
sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)

But the code breaks at getOrCreate() method.
Then get into docker hub and execute the very same script from within the container and everything executes.
What can I still gotten wrong?

The config part has an extra comma, please remove it.         "org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.0_2.12:1.6.1," "org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.6.1-28.2",
